# How do I add a button to every node with the same class

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to make a Google Chrome extension that provides a button next to every comment that does something specific. Comments don't have html id's so I did this in my content script file.

```
var cFooter = document.getElementsByClassName("comment-renderer-footer");
var btn = document.createElement("button");        
var txt = document.createTextNode("does something");       
btn.appendChild(txt);  


for(var i = 0 ; i<cFooter.length ; i++){
    cFooter.item(i).appendChild(btn);
}

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("You Clicked!")});
```

This code should make a list of all the comments and then add a button to every one of them but it does not work.

(cFooter stands for Comment footer, I want the button to be next to the dislike button.)

Manifest File:

```
"name": "Youtube Comments ",
 "description": "Youtube Comments,
 "version": "1.0",

 "manifest_version": 2,

 "browser_action":{
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "background": {
   "scripts": ["background.js"],
   "persistent": false
  },

  "icons" : {
   "64" : "icon.png" 
  },

  "permissions": ["activeTab"],

  "content_scripts": [
   {
   "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"],
   "js": ["myScript.js"]
   }
  ]
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last button should work now already (if you would change `cFooter.item(i)` to `cFooter[i]`). Here's how all of them will work, by assigning the click handler to every button, not only the last one of them:

```
var cFooter = document.getElementsByClassName("comment-renderer-footer");
for(var i = 0 ; i<cFooter.length ; i++){
    var btn = document.createElement("button");        
    var txt = document.createTextNode("does something");       
    btn.appendChild(txt); 
    cFooter[i].appendChild(btn);
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("You Clicked!")});
}
```

Comment: That worked once I added some code that prevented it from executing before the comments were loaded. Thanks!